# How to get the reference for new window object from a Component which opens the window?

Tags: reactjs, window.open

I want to focus the window, which is opened whenever row in a table is clicked, using this library, https://github.com/rmariuzzo/react-new-window. There is a method `.focus()` on window objects created by calling `window.open()`. How can I get the reference for window object, so that I can call `.focus()`?

Answer (score 1):

I was trying to do something similar but wanted the popup window to print when it opened.

Here's the solution (using React hooks):

```js
import React, {useEffect, useRef} from 'react';
import NewWindow from "react-new-window";

const PopupWindow = () => {
    const thisWindow = useRef(null);

    // This will fire when thisWindow reference changes.
    useEffect(() => {
        thisWindow.current.window.focus();
        // thisWindow.current.window.print();  // To print when the popup window loads.
    }, [thisWindow]);

    return (
        <>
            <NewWindow
                ref={thisWindow}
            >
                <p>
                   Your content here
                </p>
            </NewWindow>
        </>
    )
}

export default PopupWindow;
```

Comment: I forked new-window creating [new-improved-window](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-new-improved-window) (that uses React hooks and is written in TypeScript)

Answer (score 0):

We can access window object created in the component by using `const chartWindow = useRef(null)` on the component and access like this way, `chartWindow.current.window.focus()`